# Get NSTextField value from NSWindow beginSheet completion handler

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I created a window that slides down from the top using the beginSheet method, on the window is some NSTextFields where a user can enter data and then when the user presses the ok button to provided the completion handler NSModalResponsOK, how can I get the values from the NSTextField in the NSWindow Sheet action to the view that called the beginSheet method.  I created an initMethod that passes in the current View controller object to the NSWindow sheet modal so that I could try to set the parent view controller data properties.  I can get the data showing in the completion handler block, but cannot get the values out of the completion handler block.

here is the action to show the sheet

```
 - (IBAction)addJobDescription:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"fired add job desc");

self.addJobDescriptionViewController = [[AddJobDescriptionViewController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"AddJobDescriptionViewController" andWithViewController:self];


[[[self view] window] beginSheet:self.addJobDescriptionViewController.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode){
    
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)returnCode);
    if (returnCode == 1) {
        
        [self setJobDescriptionTableDataWithNumber:self.jobDescriptionNumberArray andWithDescription:self.jobDescriptionArray andTotal:self.JobDescriptionTotalArray];
        
        
        NSLog(@" first job description: %@",self.jobDescriptionArray[0]);
        
        
    }
    
}];
```

}

Here is the dismiss action from the NSwindow instance that has the sheet view and NSTextFields

```
 - (IBAction)endSheetView:(id)sender {

self.nEstimateViewController.jobDescriptionArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.jobDescriptionOne.stringValue,self.jobDescriptionTwo.stringValue,self.jobDescriptionThree.stringValue,self.jobDescriptionFour.stringValue, nil];
self.nEstimateViewController.JobDescriptionTotalArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.descriptionTotalOne.stringValue,self.descriptionTotalTwo.stringValue,self.descriptionTotalThree.stringValue,self.descriptionTotalFour.stringValue, nil];
self.nEstimateViewController.jobDescriptionNumberArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];



[self.window.sheetParent endSheet:self.window returnCode:NSModalResponseOK];
```

}

I have tried to make a method to call from the completion block but no dice. I want to get the data from the NSTextFields on the NSWindow Sheet view to add to an array to update a NSTableView. I am going crazy trying everything but I havent been able to find a solution.  I am thinking I need the __block some where or make the parent view controller a delegate of the NSWindow sheet instance.

Let me know if you need any other info or code.

Comment: the NSLog(@" first job description: %@",self.jobDescriptionArray[0]); does show the first value from the NSTextField but no matter what I do I cannot get the data from that array to another variable in the view controller class that called the addJobDescription: IBAction

Comment: it seems like the class instance variables stay instantiated until the completionHandler block completes and then the values across the board are nil